# create new MYSQL database from R script

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to create new MYSQL database from R script to save the new resulted tables from sampling function on it. The function takes the connection information from user, do the sampling on the specified table, then return the table after sampling.
a snapshot of my function is shown below to illustrate the idea more clearly.
`

```
SQLRowRandomSampling <- function(username,passwords,databaseName,TableName,
                                 SamplingSize){   
  #' establish the connection with the selected database
  ConnectedDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user=username,
                           password=passwords, dbname=databaseName, 
                           host='localhost')
  #' checking if the entered table exist in the selected database 
  x <- tryCatch({
      dbframe <- dbReadTable(ConnectedDb,TableName)},
    error = function(e){
      #' if not stop the function
      stop('Table does not exist! Try again please.') 
      }
    )
  #' get number of rows in the selected table
actualRowNumber <- nrow(dbframe)  
  # check if the entered sampling size is valid
if(SamplingSize<1){
    stop("Entered sampling size must be a valid number")}
  else if (SamplingSize >=  actualRowNumber){
    stop("You should eneter a sampling size that is less than the rows number
         of the selected table")} 
    
   # start row random sampling
  RandomRowSmpling<- sample_n(dbframe, SamplingSize)  
    # return the result 
return(RandomRowSmpling)}
```

the returned table "RandomRowSmpling" should be saved in new created MYSQL database to be used later on.

I know how to create new SQLite database as follow:

```
 #' create new database named Sampling_Database
    ConnectedCreatedDb <- dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(),
                             dbname= 'Sampling_Database')
```

However, for my project proposes it should be MYSQL not SQLite. any idea how to create new MYSQL database to save the resulted table on it ?

Also, i know i can add the created table to my original MYSQL database by using the following command:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = ConnectedDb, name = "RandomRowSmpling"
                            , value = RandomRowSmpling)
```

But, unfortunately I can not alter the given database.

Thank you for any help !

Comment: (1) Your first code block is missing a close `}`. (2) You should `dbDisconnect(.)`, perhaps add `on.exit(dbDisconnect(ConnectedDb), add=TRUE)` _immediately after the call to `dbConnect`_. (3) If you're saying that you cannot create a table due to perms, there is nothing in DBI or R that will allow you to bypass the authorization. If you're instead saying that you need to create a _database_ (not just a table), I know of no function that automates creation of a database; often end-users "never" have perms to do this. Am I confusing "database" and "table" in your question?

Comment: thank you for your comment. I have no permission to alter the existing database (" the one I connect to it at first from the function). However, I would like to create new empty MYSQL database not table. Then, pass the created table on it. @r2evans

Comment: I understand. There are no functions in DBI to create _databases_. In my experience, authorization to create _databases_ is very infrequent for end-users, often all they have is the ability to create _tables_ (and often only temporary/local tables, not "DBO"/main, visible to everybody). You can _try_ to create it yourself outside of R by using the cli (ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/) and reading https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-database/. If that doesn't work, your only recourse is to work with the DBA of your server.

Comment: BTW, do you have any idea how to create a Temporary table in MYSQL using R ? It could be a solution to the problem  @r2evans

Comment: You can use straight SQL, such as `create temporary table (...)`. And within the DBI package in R, both `dbCreateTsble` and `dbWriteTable` support an argument `temporary=`. You would likely benefit from reading from  https://dbi.r-dbi.org and https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/.

Comment: i am currently working with passing the query that includes "create temporary table table_name (first_column_name type_of_first_column" to MYSQL via R but it does not create anything. with no error appears! I slo, tried both dbWriteTable and dbCreateTable with temporary = TRUE. again no table is created ! @r2evans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Temporary Tables

Two methods:

1. Manual creation of the temp table, requires knowing all of the fields and field-types:

   ```r
   DBI::dbExecute(maria, "create temporary table mytemp (myint int, mychr varchar(16))")
   # [1] 0
   DBI::dbWriteTable(maria, "mytemp", data.frame(myint=1L, mychr="hello world"), append = TRUE)
   DBI::dbGetQuery(maria, "select * from mytemp")
   #   myint       mychr
   # 1     1 hello world
   ```
2. Use `temporary=TRUE` in the table creation:

   ```r
   DBI::dbWriteTable(maria, "mytemp2", data.frame(myint2=2L, mychr2="hello world again"), create=TRUE, temporary=TRUE)
   DBI::dbGetQuery(maria, "select * from mytemp2")
   #   myint2            mychr2
   # 1      2 hello world again
   ```

For both of these, this is a temporary table: it is dropped when the current connection is dropped.

```r
DBI::dbDisconnect(maria)
maria <- DBI::dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user="example-user", password="my_cool_secret", host="localhost", db = "mydb")
DBI::dbGetQuery(maria, "select * from mytemp")
# Error: Table 'mydb.mytemp' doesn't exist [1146]
DBI::dbGetQuery(maria, "select * from mytemp2")
# Error: Table 'mydb.mytemp2' doesn't exist [1146]
```

---

**Reproducibility**: I'm using docker with `mariadb`. You won't need this, since you already have an instance of MariaDB up and running somewhere.

From the shell:

```bash
$ docker run -p 3306:3306 --detach  --name some-mariadb --env MARIADB_USER=example-user --env MARIADB_PASSWORD=my_cool_secret --env MARIADB_ROOT_
PASSWORD=my-secret-pw  mariadb:latest
3babf14f7a8f2010e844a5244475d69ac4dd0856017d190bf531c5187c3e178f

$ docker exec -it  some-mariadb mariadb  -uroot -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 6
Server version: 10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204 mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> create database mydb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> grant all on mydb.* to 'example-user'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)
```

In R, the connect can be formed with:

```r
maria <- DBI::dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user="example_user", password="my_cool_secret", host="localhost", db="mydb")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @r2evans. None of these are working! when I created a temp. table using dbWriteTable and Temporary = TRUE, then test it as you did with dbGetQuery and DBI::dbExistsTable it returned True (working). However, when I call the table in another function within the same session it gives me that table does not exist. Also, when I searched MYSQL for the table using "select * from TempTable;" it return that table does not exist. I really do not know from where the problem exist.

Comment: **First**, to be very sure: your connection object never changes, you never disconnect, you never reconnect, your version of my `maria` is created at some point early in your script and never touched/deleted/recreated again. Is that right? If so, then **Second**, it might be useful to ask your DBA for help with your specific server. If they're able to see connections open and close, they may be able to monitor you running the script and see what the connection is doing. Other than that, sorry ... I don't know how else to help.

Comment: thank you @r2evans. that was my bad. I figure out that I am Re-connected each time I am calling a new function. It works perfectly now. I really appreciate your time